# swiftでextra argument error

Tags: swift

let videoInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(self.videoDevice, error: nil)!

上記のコードでextra argument 'error' in call
と出ているのですが、エラーの原因はなんでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

Swiftではバージョン2からエラー処理の新しい構文として`do〜try〜catch`が導入されました。

そりによってエラー処理のためにNSErrorのポインタを引数としてとるメソッドは`try`を利用するように変更されました。

エラーの原因は上記の変更ごあったので、すでにこのメソッドには最後の`error`引数は無いのに、引数を付けて呼び出そうとしているためです。

そのため、Extra argument 、余計な引数というエラーが出ています。